# Bad practice storing long strings in CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I understand a similar question has been asked before, but I assure you it is not a duplicate.

I have an unknown amount of `Ints` that need to be stored into coredata, preferably inside of one row. Since the amount of Ints is unknown  I was wondering if it would be good or bad practice, creating a long string of all the Ints subsequently separating them by a dash for example. Then when the string is fetched from CoreData I would use a simple `Split` to split them up into their respective form. Is anything mentioned bad practice? If so, how would you do it differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have to query the `Ints`, you can use an NSArray as a Transformable property.

This will be converted in binary and stored as BLOB.

Here the example:

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on how one might achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: I hope the image helps... If you use a .m just create the property as NSArray, core data should take care of this automatically. Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I knew how to do that, I just thought you meant something else! Will I be able to simply fetch this like ay other object from CoreData? Or will the Managed Object take care of it?

Comment: Yes, you fetch the entity and the property will be deserialized by core data as soon as you access it.